# How to position connect off screen without using flex box?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to position content slightly off screen, but when I set it to absolute (as seen in demo below) the "home" section doesn't expand to fit and causes school bars when the screen isn't larger than the images. If I change it to "responsive" the images are scaled down, I would like them full size.

Is there a way to position the content slightly off screen using flexbox? If not what is a method I could use to get this done the right way? I want 1/2 of the 3rd image to be slightly off screen.

Thanks, I hope my question is clear. To view it functioning as intended please click "run snippet" and then click "full screen" on a desktop. To see the scroll bar simply do not click the "full screen" button.

```css
.hero-img {

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.img-container {
    max-width:345px;
    max-height:580px;
}

.inner{
    position: absolute;
    right: -172px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="home" class="main lg:pl-28 flex flex-wrap flex-row w-full h-screen">
    <div class="flex flex-col w-full lg:w-5/12 justify-center lg:pr-28 bg-green-200">
        <p class="text-lg mb-0 text-gray-600">Title 1</p>
        <h1 class="mb-4 text-3xl md:text-5xl font-bold leading-tight text-center md:text-left slide-in-bottom-h1">Title 2</h1>
        <p class="leading-normal text-base md:text-2xl mb-8 text-center md:text-left slide-in-bottom-subtitle">Title 3</p>
    </div>
    
    <!--Right Col-->
    <div class="outer w-full lg:w-7/12 overflow-x-hidden relative flex items-center bg-red-200">
        <div class="flex gap-4 inner">
            <div class="flex-initial img-container">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580" class="hero-img">
            </div>
            <div class="flex-initial img-container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580" class="hero-img">
            </div>
            <div class="flex-initial img-container">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580" class="hero-img">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```